# Include new data on some specific position in the tree

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I have structured array with data and need to append to node X additional data. The node X is specified by its path in other array ($path).

```
$data = [
183013 =>
    [
        183014 => [
            183018,
            183019 => [
                183021,
                183022 => [
                    183023
                ]
            ],
            183020
        ],
        183016,
        183017
    ]
];

$path = [183013, 183014, 183019, 183021];
$new_data = [183030 => [183031]];
```

So, I need to append $new_data to the element 183021.
The depth of $data or $path is unlimited.

Comment: all the numbers are unique, right?

Comment: You can try by searching and using array_push method

Comment: i think the numbers are not unique

Comment: @EugenA *i think the numbers are not unique* - then your path could be confusing to search within nonunique numbers

Comment: Created this to play: http://phplab.io/lab/iwnXI

Comment: one element cannot have same number two times, so path could not be confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some times to play on phplab.io/lab/iwnXI

I created this:

## Data

```
<?php
$data = [
    183013 => [
        183014 => [
            183018,
            183019 => [
                183021,
                183022 => [
                    183023
                ]
            ],
            183020
        ],
        183016,
        183017
    ]
];

$path = [183013, 183014, 183019, 183021];

$new_data = [183030 => [183031]];
```

## Solution 1 - Recursive function

Provide data to the function, and each node will be added.
We need to remove the final numeric values (i.e. '0 => 183020')

```
<?php function appendIntoArrayTree(array $source, array $path, array $values) {
    $key = array_shift($path);

    if ( isset($source[$key]) && is_array($source[$key]) ) {
        $source[$key] = appendIntoArrayTree($source[$key], $path, $values);
    }
    else {
        // search if the current $path key exist as 'value' on the $source (i.e.: '0 => 183021')
        if( !is_null($foundKey = array_search($key, $source)) ) {
            unset($source[$foundKey]);
        }
        $source[$key] = $values; // final
    }

    return $source;
}
```

And the output:

```
var_dump( appendIntoArrayTree($data, $path, $new_data) );
```

## Solution 2 - eval mode

It's a trick, and I does not encourage to use it (moreover some servers does not allow the usage of `eval()`)

```
function appendIntoArrayTreeWithEval(array $source, array $path, array $values) {
    $path_last = $path[count($path) - 1];
    $path_string = implode('',
      array_map(function($v) {
        return '[' . $v . ']';
      }, array_slice($path, 0, count($path) - 1))
     ); // Convert $path = ['a', 'b', 'c'] to string [a][b] (last 'c' not used)

    $tmp = null;
    eval('$tmp = isset($source' . $path_string . ') ? $source' . $path_string . ' : null;');
    if( is_null($tmp) ) {
        // $source[a][b] does not exists
        eval('$source' . $path_string . '[' . $path_last . '] = $values;');
    }
    else if( is_array($tmp) ) {
        if( !is_null($key = array_search($path_last, $tmp)) ) {
            // key exists with 'numeric' array key value (0 =>, 1 =>, ...)
            eval('unset($source' . $path_string . '[' . $key . ']);'); // remove
        }
        eval('$source' . $path_string . '[' . $path_last . '] = $values;');
    }  else {
        // is string/numeric/... Error. SHould not use 0/1/2 ... values
    }
    return $source;
}
```

And the output

```
var_dump( appendIntoArrayTreeWithEval($data, $path, $new_data) );
```

> Solution 1 is the best :)
>
> (We also tried `array merge recursive` function, but it does not work)